# Why is apache -X stuck in a pselec6() NULL loop?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, apache-2.4, apache2, apache-1.3

version 2.4

pselect6(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=100000000}, NULL) = 0 (Timeout)

Repeats forever using strace. Only one httpd process enabled.

Comment: I also have the same problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74439668/apache-process-gets-stuck-while-processing Let me know if you got the solution

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Here is my logs

```
netstat -tulpn

Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      729/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22825           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2728/php            
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:23004           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2752/php            
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22928           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2742/php            
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1072/sshd: /usr/sbi 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      971/mysqld          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33060         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      971/mysqld          
tcp6       0      0 :::9100                 :::*                    LISTEN      1074312/node_export 
tcp6      71      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2207/apache2        
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1072/sshd: /usr/sbi 
tcp6     512      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      2207/apache2        
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           729/systemd-resolve 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:500             0.0.0.0:*                           1073/charon         
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4500            0.0.0.0:*                           1073/charon         
udp6       0      0 :::500                  :::*                                1073/charon         
udp6       0      0 :::4500                 :::*                                1073/charon
```

Apache2 stuck and only listening on ipv6 tcp.

Here is the stack trace.

```
2207  pselect6(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}, NULL) = 0 (Timeout)
2207  wait4(-1, 0x7ffedc77b084, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0
2207  times({tms_utime=3026 /* 30.26 s */, tms_stime=6010 /* 60.10 s */, tms_cutime=369020 /* 3690.20 s */, tms_cstime=174724 /* 1747.24 s */}) = 1819843847
2207  pselect6(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}, NULL) = 0 (Timeout)
2207  wait4(-1, 0x7ffedc77b084, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0
2207  times({tms_utime=3026 /* 30.26 s */, tms_stime=6010 /* 60.10 s */, tms_cutime=369020 /* 3690.20 s */, tms_cstime=174724 /* 1747.24 s */}) = 1819843947
2207  pselect6(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}, NULL) = 0 (Timeout)
2207  wait4(-1, 0x7ffedc77b084, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0
2207  times({tms_utime=3026 /* 30.26 s */, tms_stime=6010 /* 60.10 s */, tms_cutime=369020 /* 3690.20 s */, tms_cstime=174724 /* 1747.24 s */}) = 1819844047
2207  pselect6(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}, NULL^C
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/531404)